# application insert/update query optimization

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

I'm creating windows form application which running a lot of insert/update queries. Even inserting small amount of information (700 rows) you have to wait for some minutes. 
Here is code I am using :

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
        listItems.Add( row[dt.Columns[i].ColumnName], ListOperator.Comma);
      }
    var insQry = "INSERT INTO table ( ";
    insQry = insQry + colList + " ) VALUES ( " + listItems.ToString() + " )";
    var tbl = server.RunQuery(insQry);

//at running time this query would look like this "INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (value1, value2)"
```

What looked strange for me that when I am restoring data (for restoring data I am using update/delete queries) I was inserted, the query performance take only few seconds.

What could be a possibility to shorten insert query performance time? Maybe there could help threads? (if so, what kind of threads? asynchronous? parallel threads?).

All ideas are welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is because you are using string concatenation to build your queries. You should use parameters. There are many adavtages to using them, including performance and safety from SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, did you wrap your inserts in a transaction? `using (var trans = new TransactionScope(){...}`

Secondly, why not use a a `DataAdapter`?